# What to pass to printf()

Tags: c, printf

ALL,

Let's say I have 2 double values:

```
3.567
0.412
```

I want to display them as:

```
3.567
 .412
```

Which format I should pass to printf() in order to achieve this? The format should handle both cases.

Thank you.

Comment: Also have a look at the http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/